# How to delete a UEFI Authenticated Variable?

Tags: uefi

I write a UEFI Shell app to experiment with UEFI Authenticated variables. I can create an Authenticated variable and then update it by signing with the same private key. However, when trying to delete it later, I get a security violation error.

Stepping through the EDKII code in SecurityPkg\Library\AuthVariableLib\AuthService.c, I can see that to delete an authenticated variable, the UserPhysicalPresent() function must return TRUE. The default implementation of UserPhysicalPresent() is in PlatformSecureLibNull.c, always returning TRUE, but apparently several real devices from major OEMs do actually implement this function and deletion always fails.

What would be the correct way to delete a UEFI authenticated variable created from UEFI Shell or from within an OS? How to satisfy the user physical presence requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it seems to be a bug in EDKII Variable Service implementation - there should be no Physical Presence requirement to delete an authenticated variable. If the firmware is affected by this issue, there may be no way to delete an authenticated variable. Be careful - once written, the custom authenticated variable can be updated, but cannot be deleted. I had to physically flash firmware on my devices that I experimented with to get rid of the authenticated variables I wrote.